# Открытие и прокрутка страницы

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью JavaScript открыть сайт и сделать прокрутку страницы?

Данный код не работает:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.spravkaweb.ru";
window.scrollBy(0, 200);
```

Через обработчик `onload` тоже не работает.

Браузер Chrome, страница с полосой прокруткой.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Как только текущая страница закрывается, её скрипты дейстравовать перестают. Исполняются только скрипты новой страницы.

Если тебе нужно прокрутить к какому-то месту на той странице, используй якорь в разметке:

```
<div id=smth>То место, куда тебе надо попасть</div>
```

а для перехода, соответственно, такой код:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.spravkaweb.ru#smth";
```

Comment: Можно попытаться извратиться через `iframe`. Единственное - так просто страницу внутри `iframe` не прокрутить.